# How to get boost multiprecision number parts?

Tags: c++, boost, interop, decimal

Say I have this *number*:

```
// bmp = boost::multiprecision
bmp::cpp_dec_float n("123456789.1234567891011121314");
```

its backend data are:

```
[0]  1         unsigned int
[1]  23456789  unsigned int
[2]  12345678  unsigned int
[3]  91011121  unsigned int
[4]  31400000  unsigned int
...  0
[15] 0         unsigned int
```

which is exactly what I want to get; unfortunately, I don't find a way to get either both parts of my number as `bmp::int128_t` --for instance--, or the underlying data of my number.

That is, I like something like this exists:

```
bmp::int128_t integerPart;
bmp::int128_t floatPart;
n.getParts(integerPart, floatPart);
```

or

```
auto&& data = n.data(); // which is actually private when using `cpp_dec_float`.
```

Anyway, does someone known how to do what I am trying to achieve?

For the record, I need this to express a big decimal number as a C# decimal for the sake of interoperability.

Answer (score 1):

From the boost documentation the back end is intentionally opaque as it may change at any time without warning. (`Class template cpp_dec_float fulfils all of the requirements for a Backend type. Its members and non-member functions are deliberately not documented: these are considered implementation details that are subject to change.`) from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/ref/cpp_dec_ref.html

As far as I can see you have two choices here. You can look at the source code for the specific version of the backend class you're using, access it from your `number` using the `backend` method, and hope that the backend never changes (especially consider changes that only broke binary format and not compilation).

Alternately I would recommend you take the string representation of the `cpp_dec_float` and split it into the two parts yourself, using the `string` or `char*` constructors for the underlying integral types you're interested in.

Comment: +1, with the additional note that the Boost public license allows copying for almost any use, including commercial.  If the internal representation if some version is exactly what the OP needs/wants, then if the Boost.MultiPrecision owners cannot be convinced to freeze one implementation, the OP can freeze it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is you are looking for, try...

```
cpp_dec_float_100 myreal(100);
cpp_dec_float_100 int_part = myreal.backend().extract_integer_part();
```

The type is still cpp_dec_float_100, but only contains the integer part. 
I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that you can probably use `eval_frexp` to get the values you're looking for, although you'll still have to check that they fit into the C# Decimal type.  See the manual on Boost.Multiprecision backend requirements here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/ref/backendconc.html

You could always just do the longhand math and range checking; if you're not transferring too many numbers, this might be fast enough.

Having said all that, you are welcome to be naughty and do something like:

```
#define private public
#define protected public
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#undef private
#undef protected
```

But if it breaks in a future release, you get to keep both pieces.

---

Hey, thanks for the downvote with no comment.  That's really helpful.

To clarify my comments above:

Using `eval_frexp`: after further research, it seems that the `eval_frexp(b, cb, pi)` is still only offering powers of 2, not powers of 10 as seems to be required for the `Decimal` type.  So I suspect that you have to do the arithmetic in long form if you want to use only the public interface.

Abusing `private` members: The authors and maintainers of the Boost.Multiprecision classes designed them according to certain guidelines; they apparently ranked future-proofing as more important than providing access to the internal structure:

> Class template cpp_dec_float fulfils all of the requirements for a Backend type. Its members and non-member functions are deliberately not documented: these are considered implementation details that are subject to change.  (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/ref/cpp_dec_ref.html)

My proposal, which was clearly marked as "naughty" and with the warning that it would likely break in a future release, was to impose the design needs of the OP ahead of those of the author of B.MP.

The very cleanest method might be to propose a change to the `cpp_dec_float` class, where the internal structure is exposed; given a compelling use case, and an analysis of how much the code has or hasn't changed historically, it might even be accepted.

Hope this helps.  If readers still have issues with it, please feel free to downvote, but please let me know which part bothers you so I can try to improve it.

Comment: It wasn't me, but `#define`ing keywords is undefined behavior and (almost?) never a solid solution to problems

Comment: Oh, no argument there.  I tried to phrase the original reply (and my snarky comment about the downvote) to be clear that this is not something that is a good idea for production use.  If the OP really needs this capability long-term, then if they can't convince the B.MP maintainers, they should just fork it and suck it into their code base -- the BPL allows for that.  I was just trying to offer a "it's 11pm and you need it tomorrow" solution.  Maybe that's worth a downvote, dunno.

Comment: Amusing anecdote: I tried to create a "#define private public; NO REGRETS" meme on the internal meme generator at my current company... only to be redirected to an *existing* example.  So I'm guess I'm not the only demented soul with this idea.  :)